# UIViewController adding subview gives me error: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am getting the following error and I am not sure what is causing it.

```
2011-02-06 23:38:12.580 SApp[9648:207] -[Record superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f2a350
2011-02-06 23:38:12.583 SApp[9648:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Record superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f2a350'
```

Steps that are creating the error:

- My custom class is being added to the
  app delegate's window.
- My class is a subclass of UIViewController.
- In my custom class I am adding a subview (Record) which is another
  subclass of UIViewController. - THIS
  is when the error started happening.

**Code that is causing the error**:

```
[self.view addSubview:[self.tabBarControllers objectAtIndex:0]];
```

I have all my .h files included where they should be, so I am not sure what is causing this.  And ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot add a `UIViewController` (Record) as a subview of another view. Instead, add the view managed by that view controller as a subview.

```
UIViewController *recordController = [self.tabBarControllers objectAtIndex:0];

[self.view addSubview:recordController.view];
```

Comment: Ha, thank you!  It seems so obvious now that you point this out. :)

Comment: What @NicHubbard said